Initialize and use ADE7880 ADC via SPI in Linux
I am working with the ADE7880 ADC and I am attempting to initialize it and use it to read and write registers via SPI in C on a Linux system. My goal is to capture ADC data through SPI, but I am encountering difficulties.
Here are the specifics of my issue:

I have written to 4 registers to initialize the ADC.

I am trying to read data from a specific register, but I am not receiving the expected default data or the data I wrote.


I am unsure if the ADC is being initialized correctly or if the data is being read properly.
I referred to this link for guidance, but I am still experiencing issues.
Could someone please provide assistance or suggest what might be going wrong?
before connecting ADC:

after connecting ADC:

code:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

// Define the ADC registers
#define CFMODE 0xE610
#define RUNREG 0xE228
#define ADD1 0xE7FE
#define ADD2 0xE7E3
//#define ADC_REG_STATUS 0x04
#define CHECKSUM 0xE51F
//#define ADC_REG_ERROR_FLAGS 0x06

// Define the ADC configuration values
#define ADC_CONFIG1_VALUE 0x00A0
#define ADC_CONFIG2_VALUE 0x0001
#define ADC_CONFIG3_VALUE 0xAD
#define ADC_CONFIG4_VALUE 0x80

// Define the SPI device and frequency
#define SPI_DEVICE "/dev/spidev0.0"
#define SPI_FREQUENCY 100000 // 100 kHz

int main() {
int fd = open(SPI_DEVICE, O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0) {
perror("Failed to open SPI device");
return -1;
}

// Set the SPI frequency
uint32_t speed = SPI_FREQUENCY;
if (ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed) < 0) {
perror("Failed to set SPI frequency");
return -1;
}

// Set SPI mode
int mode = SPI_MODE_0;
if (ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode) < 0) {
perror("Error setting SPI mode");
close(fd);
return 1;
}

// Read the default CHECKSUM register value
uint8_t tx_buffer[2];
tx_buffer[0] = CHECKSUM;
tx_buffer[1] = 0x01; // Read command

ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, tx_buffer, 2);
if (bytes_written < 0) {
perror("Failed to send read command");
return -1;
}
/*
// Send dummy byte (0xFF) before reading data
tx_buffer[0] = 0xFF;
bytes_written = write(fd, tx_buffer, 1);
if (bytes_written < 0) {
perror("Failed to send dummy byte");
return -1;
}
*/
// Read 4 bytes (32 bits) from the CHECKSUM register
uint8_t rx_buffer[4];
ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, rx_buffer, 4);
if (bytes_read < 0) {
perror("Failed to read register value");
return -1;
}

printf("Default CHECKSUM register value: 0x%x%x%x%x\n", rx_buffer[0], rx_buffer[1], rx_buffer[2], rx_buffer[3]);

// Close the SPI device
close(fd);
return 0;
} 


I referred to this link for guidance what link?

First check that you have connected circuits correctly, and that the voltage levels are correct. Then hook up the data bus to SPI capable logic analyzer and try to see if data frames are correctly sent and received.

Welcome to SO. "I have written to 4 registers" You are not writing some novel where the reader shall use their imagination for everything that is not written. With code you must provide exactly what your are doing. Don't describe code but show it. You can edit your question to include a MCVE demonstrating your issue.

With SPI you not only need correct wiring (and some pullups maybe) but also correct protocol configuration. You could have incorrect polarity of your CLK line or providing/expecting the data on the wrong edge. You need to look closely into your datasheet to check for correct setup

@polfosolఠ_ఠ i added the link

@user694733 I tried my device with STM32 and it works well with it, transmit and receive both are working properly and waveform are also okay. but the problem is with ADC and on thing i tried my device API with beaglebone black and with that i am facing same problem.

@Gerhardh Thank you for your input. I apologize for any mistakes as I am new to this. I tried using pull-ups, but it didn't work. Any further advice would be greatly appreciated.

No need to apologize. But as I mentioned, you need to show us what you are doing. Please edit your question to include your code. If you have some suitable equipment, you should also include some trace from the signals on the SPI lines.

@Gerhardh
i attached code and image of signal after connecting device with ADC and before connecting device

@Gerhardh please check the code

i taken waveform with STM32 everything isoaky with it but the problem is with ADC & beaglebone black

"but the problem is with ADC & beaglebon" This covery basically everything in your project. Could you please respond to my comments from chat? And please respond in the chat.

@Gerhardh i can't reply, it says i need 20 reputation

@Gerhardh I am trying this since so many days but it is not happening

It seems the chat is no longer usable. But you can still read my comments there and provide the missing information in the question or maybe here in comments.

unable to read discussion @Gerhardh

Then here is a copy: To be clear, I don't know how to access SPI under Linux. The example you linked, shows that they send 3*8 bits before they read 1-4 bytes. Your code does not contain a similar part. ALso as I mentioned, your CLK polarity is wrong and without seeing CS and the data lines it is hard to tell if you even configured the SPI device correctly.
The code also does not show anything that would match "I have written to 4 registers to initialize the ADC."
Where did you get the idea for the code you have written? Any template?

Register CHECKSUM has address 0xE51F which you try to squeeze into a single uint8_t. That won't fly. Your linked repository shows that reading a 32 bit register fiirst sends 0x01 and then low 8 bits and high 8 bits of the address followed by 4 read accesses. See function ADE_Read32 for reference. Your buffer is too small and you add values in wrong order.
You urgently need to trace the SPI signals when you do the test with STM which works as you said. Then compare with signals created by your Linux code.

As far as I can see, you have a scope with 4 channels. There should be no problem with capturing all SPI signals.
